# Pandas head command does not give the expected results

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

I can't get pandas features to work for me. Here's a simple example. I read in a kaggle data set to a data frame with the following commands:

```
import pandas as pd
train_data=pd.read_csv('kaggle_train.csv',header=None)
```

Then I ask it for the first five data rows using the head command:

```
train_data.head()
```

Instead of getting the first five rows of data, I get this output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns:
X0     5  non-null values
X1     5  non-null values
X2     5  non-null values
X3     5  non-null values
X4     5  non-null values
X5     5  non-null values
X6     5  non-null values
X7     5  non-null values
X8     5  non-null values
X9     5  non-null values
X10    5  non-null values
X11    5  non-null values
X12    5  non-null values
X13    5  non-null values
X14    5  non-null values
X15    5  non-null values
X16    5  non-null values
X17    5  non-null values
X18    5  non-null values
X19    5  non-null values
X20    5  non-null values
X21    5  non-null values
X22    5  non-null values
X23    5  non-null values
X24    5  non-null values
X25    5  non-null values
X26    5  non-null values
X27    5  non-null values
X28    5  non-null values
X29    5  non-null values
X30    5  non-null values
X31    5  non-null values
X32    5  non-null values
X33    5  non-null values
X34    5  non-null values
X35    5  non-null values
X36    5  non-null values
X37    5  non-null values
X38    5  non-null values
X39    5  non-null values
X40    5  non-null values
dtypes: float64(40), int64(1)
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

I'm running Python 2.7.3 in an IPython window version 0.13.1-1 on an HP Pavilion laptop running Windows Vista Home Premium Service Pack 2

Comment: Are you using IPython in the terminal or in a browser-based notebook? I'd suggest using it in a browser-based notebook if, like myself, you prefer to see the data outright. After importing the HTML display, you can use the command `display(HTML(dataframe.head().to_html()))` to view the data.

Answer (score 2):

By default, pandas displays a summary form of the output if it has too many columns to be displayed in a readable way.  You can force it to display the actual data by doing `print train_data.head().to_string()`, but the output may be difficult to read because you have so many columns.

Comment: This is indeed correct, and as this is confusing to newcomers, this will change in upcoming pandas 0.13. There always (possibly truncated) data will be shown, and the summary view can be requested with `df.info()`.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I tried to upvote, but apparently my reputation is not high enough! Can anyone tell me how many columns is "too many"?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer, this is the summary view of the DataFrame (as there are too many columns to display*). You can see the first rows and columns using iloc/;

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,100))

In [12]: df.iloc[:3, :4]  # first 3 rows and 4 columns
Out[12]: 
          0         1         2         3
0  1.271254 -1.057603  0.411799  0.523563
1  0.828735  0.306329  0.508435 -1.214766
2  0.684236 -1.541779  2.354181 -1.036631
```

* *By default this is 20, but you can change it in the options (to more than the number of columns):*

```
pd.options.display.max_columns = 101
```

*Now `df.head()` will show all rows "as expected".*

As noted, in 0.13 this behaviour is changing to show more of the frame by default (up to the first `max_columns` columns):

```
In [21]: pd.options.display.max_columns = 5  # by default this is 20

In [22]: df.head()
Out[22]: 
          0         1         2         3         4    
0 -0.269232  0.059875  1.420564  2.106847  1.999374 ...
1 -0.625981 -0.459105 -0.818499 -0.375799  2.619382 ...
2 -1.027394 -0.084883  0.294238  0.636856 -0.356340 ...
3  1.735632  0.235712 -0.283334 -0.191722 -0.885285 ...
4 -0.154700  1.640423  1.021390  0.636728  0.918846 ...

[5 rows x 100 columns]
```

Comment: When I tried "pd.options.display.max_columns = 101" in the Spyder ide for Python(x,y), the error message said: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'options'

Comment: You're using an older version of pandas, best to upgrade, you can search the docs for your specific version for options... I can't recall offhand how you used to do this, something set_option

Comment: @AnneDwyer it used to be `pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 101)`, but will depend on your version (I recommend upgrading to the latest stable version).

Comment: @AnneDwyer presumably there isn't an `iloc` either (if it's [pre 0.11](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#selection-choices)), in which case you need to use (the more ambiguous) `ix`.

Comment: Would love to upgrade to a higher version. Anybody have a easy to follow tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: @AnneDwyer how did you install it? The usual was is to use pip: `pip install pandas --upgrade`